Best way to keep booking data updated on schedule via API
Advice needed on the best way to orchestrate the below.
We have a booking system which provides an API to get bookings by meeting room (resource id) within a date range i.e. start and end date. e.g.  /api/getdata?id=""&start_date=""&end_date=""
The idea is to get the data from the API on a schedule basis and keep our delta table updated accordingly.
My first though is to get the initial load to the delta table for the following period 2024-01-01 - 2024-08-31.
This will give the past bookings and future bookings for the next month.
But what would be the best strategy or logic for the subsequent schedule requests, taking into account that bookings for a resource can change (or even be deleted) if the end date has not passed.
Hope this is clear, but if not let me know.
Any advise would be appreciated.

If a booking gets edited - can we assume that neither start nor end date can be set lower than today then?

If a booking gets deleted - will the API still return it then (with some additional field indicating that is was deleted), or will those bookings then simply be missing from all future requests?

If there was a booking for 2024-08-10 to 2024-08-15, but that gets rescheduled to 2024-12-10 to 2024-12-15 now - then you probably won't "catch" it, if you keep reading the "future bookings for the next month." You will get it again in November - but in the meantime, the already existing booking in August will probably have to be deleted/hidden in your system. The API should hopefully provide some unique identifier? Then you will have to delete/hide bookings that you don't get in your current API request any more, that hard a start date > than what you are currently requesting from the API.

Hi @CBroe , thanks for your comments! To answer some of your questions. If editing a booking the start or end cannot be less than today's date. If a booking is deleted, the API will no longer return a result for that booking. The booking returns a unique id for the booking and its created date and modified date. Its quite a challenging one, at least for me to get my head around.

"If a booking is deleted, the API will no longer return a result for that booking." - so get them out of your system again, you need to delete/hide all bookings, which you don't get back from the API. But of course only for the range for which you currently requested data. That would then also mean, that bookings that have been moved far in to the future - outside of the start and end date you are requesting - would also "disappear", at least for now. But that's not much different from any booking in, say, December 2024, that your initial request would not have captured either.

Might be just easier to focus on bookings that have already passed i.e end_date < "todays" date.
